# Create sequential text file from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an object:

```
public class Game {
    int idGame;
    String teamHome;
    String teamVisit;
    int goalsHome;
    int goalsVisit;
}
```

A constructor:

```
public Game(int id, String Home, String Visit, int goalsHome, int goalsVisit){
    this.idGame = id;
    this.teamHome = Home;
    this.teamVisit = Visit;
    this.goalsHome = goalsHome;
    this.goalsVisit = goalsVisit;    
}
```

and all the get/set

```
public int getIdGame(){
    return idGame;
}
public String getteamLocal(){
    return teamLocal;
}
public String getteamVisit(){
    return teamVisit;
}
..... etc.
```

I capture the data using a GUI interface and create objects in an  array list

```
ArrayList<Game> GameList = new ArrayList();
......
Game game = new Game();
game.setteamLocal(teamLocal);
game.setteamVisita(teamVisita);
game.setgoalsLocal(goalsLocal);
game.setgoalsVisita(goalsVisita);
game.setIdGame(id);
GameList.add(Game);
```

So far so go, I have the ArrayList with all the data from the diferent games.

I now need to create a sequential text file with all this data and this is my problem. I'm trying

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("games.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(GameList);
oos.close();
```

ArrayLists are supposed to be Serializable but I' getting an java.io.NotSerializableException: ....

Any idea how to create the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Game object is not serializable.  Once you fix that, it should work.

ie.,
class Game implements Serializable

Comment: That simple ah?   Can't believe I missed that!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be human readable text use a object to xml or json parser (Jackson) or print pipe separated strings.

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("games.txt");
out.println(game.getXXX()+"|");//...
...catch
finally out.close